# Matlab multiply matrix with matrix along third dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `A` of size `m x n x 3` and I have have a `3x3` matrix `K`. Now what I want to do is something like this:

```
for row = 1:m
 for col = 1:n
  A(row,col,:) = K*[A(row,col,1);A(row,col,2);A(row,col,3)];
 end
end
```

I'd like to have an efficient solution without a loop, as loops are very slow, because `m x n` is usually the size of an image.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
M = 1000;
N = 1000;
L = 3;
A = rand(M,N,L);
K = rand(L,L);
Q = reshape((K * reshape( A, [M*N, L] ).' ).', [M, N, L]);
```

Error check:

```
Z = zeros(M,N,L);
for mm = 1 : M
  for nn = 1 : N
    Z(mm,nn,:) = K * squeeze( A(mm,nn,:) );
  end
end
max( abs( Z(:) - Q(:) ) )

ans =

      0
```

Comment: I definitely like the runtime, but when I run my code and yours and I compare the two outputs with isequal(Q,A) gives me 0, thus the two resulting matrices are not the same?!

Comment: @SemtexB I added an example to demonstrate that my code is correct. Are you sure the error is not on your end? How much error are you seeing? Relying on `isequal` for floating point numbers is not always a good idea.

Comment: Very nice. This is the way I would have done it as well.

Comment: `for row = 1:rows
    for col = 1:cols
        Cube(row,col,:) = KNew*[Cube(row,col,1);Cube(row,col,2);Cube(row,col,3)];
    end
end

Q = reshape((KNew * reshape( Cube, [rows*cols, 3] ).' ).', [rows, cols, 3]);

isequal(Q,Cube)
max( abs( Cube(:) - Q(:) ) )
sum(sum((Q-Cube).^2))`
gives output
`ans =

     0


ans =

    46940000


ans(:,:,1) =

   2.6636e+20


ans(:,:,2) =

   1.0880e+20


ans(:,:,3) =

     0`

Comment: @SemtexB You are calculating `Q` using the new values of `Cube`. Calculate `Q` prior to the for loops.